# removing svg line new last node on every click in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, svg

I am currently developing an offline application and I use Interactive svg. my problem is on removing svg lines last node on click event.. the case is... it works at (first click), it removes the last node. but when i try it again..(2nd click) it doesn't work anymore. I can't seem to find the problem.

this my code on creating svg line segments..

```
var glblLineNode;
var tempX=[], tempY=[], tempLine=[];

function drawRoad()
{   
       var path = glblGeogSorc.getElementsByTagName("path")
       for (var loop=0; loop<Slct.length; loop++)
       {
         path[loop].addEventListener("mousedown", function(e)
         {
            if(e.button == 0 &&  glblenblroad === true)
            {

                var mousex = e.clientX - matrixE;
                var mousey = e.clientY - matrixF;

                tempX.push(mousex), tempY.push(mousey);

                if(tempX.length > 1)
                {

                    var road = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");                          
                        road.x1.baseVal.value = tempX[tempX.length -1];
                        road.y1.baseVal.value = tempY[tempY.length -1];
                        road.x2.baseVal.value = tempX[tempX.length -2];
                        road.y2.baseVal.value = tempY[tempY.length -2];
                        road.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke", "#686968");
                        road.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-width", "14.520");
                        road.setAttributeNS(null, "stroke-linecap", "round");
                        road.setAttributeNS(null, "fill", "none");
                        glblGeogSorc.getElementsByTagName("g")[0].appendChild(road);

                        tempLine.push(road);
                        glblLineNode = road;

                }

            }
        },false);

    }

}
```

Let's just assume that function drawRoad() is been executed,
then here is my code on removing lastnode of the created svg line from function drawRoad()

```
delLastNode.addEventListener("click", function()   //  delLastNode is a var for my button
{

   glblGeogSorc.parentNode.removeChild(glblLineNode);  //glblLineNode is global var prior to the line created
   tempLine.pop();                                    //as well as tempLine[]
   tempX.pop();                                       
   tempY.pop();                                       

},false);
```

it works for the very first click delLastNode(Button) but when try to click it again
it doesn't work anymore.. my goal is to remove every new last node on every time i want to click delLastNode(Button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`glblLineNode` is being overwritten on each loop, so it only holds a reference to the last variable (because the loop ends). When you remove the element then that reference is broken, this is why it only works once.

You function should look like this:

```
delLastNode.addEventListener("click", function()   //  delLastNode is a var for my button
{
   // .pop() returns the removed element, so let's store it. 
   var deleteElem = tempLine.pop(); 
   glblGeogSorc.parentNode.removeChild(deleteElem);
   tempX.pop();                                       
   tempY.pop();                                       
},false);
```

No need for global variables.

Comment: now it works perfectly.. :) thanks a lot sir.. I just had to store it in a local variable.. and that's it..